# SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS question when using two ORDER BYs

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query that gets a result, limits it and then does a sort around the limited results. Something like:

```
(SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM  table ... ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,15) ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Using

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total
```

after will always return 15 due to the sub sort. Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll have to do a `COUNT(*)` in a separate query.